# Docker Desktop for Mac doesn't run the container in localhost with the port specified

Tags: macos, docker, containers

I am Using Docker Desktop for macOS. It's working fine with pulling the image from docker hub. But when I run the container by mapping the ports, the ​container is working but I cannot see anything in the browser. The localhost doesn't work.

I am using the command below:

**docker run -p 9090:80 tomcat:latest.**

When I run the above command, the container is running in the cmd terminal of mac but when I open the safari browser by typing **localhost:9090**, it's not working.

[Running Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnBd4.png)

[Localhost:9090 doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmBFJ.png)

Comment: What commands are you running?  How have you built and run the image?  What actual error are you getting, and from what program?  Please include these details as text (not images) in the question itself (not behind links).

Comment: @sonamwangmo, the default port for tomcat is 8080, so if you'll do a docker run -p 9090:8080 tomcat:latest, it will work ;)

Comment: @arcticless Thank you. It worked. I thought 80 and 8080 is the same